# using if statement with button actions and prompts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like my script to do three things depending on the button the user clicked.

1. Display a message that allows the user to go through a piece of information and confirm everything is correct. (This part works but I am having issues with getting 2 and 3 to work)
2. If the user selects yes, I would like to display a message that informs the user that an email is on its way.
3. If the user selects no, I would like to display a message with a link that tells the user to update sheet info.

Here is my code:
"sid" is my spreadsheet

```
var response = ui.alert(`Hi, please confirm the recipient details Recipient: ${decisionmaker}
  Email: ${email} Is this information correct?`,ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
      
      sid.show('Your email is on its way to the recipient);
    }
    else if(response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.NO)
    {sid.show('Please update your data sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KTMLvumkQK-X5R6utwzSVSEE0k8OcszzQ9zQPEqdxBQ/edit#gid=0');

    }
```

Comment: Do you see colors in  the code you posted?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This post contains a list of requirements, some code but it's not clear what is the issue that you have /  what is being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function myfunk() {
  const sid = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const d = "bob";
  var response = ui.alert(`Hi, please confirm the recipient details Recipient: ${d} Email: ${d} Is this information correct?`, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
    sid.show(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p> Your email is on its way to the recipient</p'));
    }  else if (response == ui.Button.NO) {
    sid.show(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>Please update your data sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KTMLvumkQK-X5R6utwzSVSEE0k8OcszzQ9zQPEqdxBQ/edit#gid=0,</p>'));

  }
}
```